# Hive Table Extract

Tags: hive

Trying to export a very large HIVE table out to .csv.  I've tried a few options based on issues I've found in the output but none seem to get me what I'm looking for which is essentially a carbon copy, with headers of the table "bigtable."

```
#!/bin/bash
hive -e "insert overwrite local directory '/home/centos/data'
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
Select * from schema.bigtable a, schema.filter b where a.id = b.id"
cat /home/centos/data* > /home/centos/data/FullFile.csv
```

This worked, took a while, but had no headers.  Found a bunch of SO posts stating that headers and insert overwrite wasn't going to play nicely.  Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps someone out!

```
hive -e "Select * from schema.table a, schema.tabletwo b where a.column = b.column"
cat /home/data/* > /home/data/File.csv
```